# PHP json_decode(), used with a class defined by me, returns a stdClass

Tags: php, json

if i pass to the json_decode() function a JSON string relative to an object of a class defined by me, it returns a stdClass object (then loses the methods) instead of original class object...any suggestions?

Comment: Please, read your question and ask yourself if you'd know what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

Try serialize() and unserialize()

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a format for data, not code. You should initialize your objects with the decoded JSON data instead of expecting them to be created directly. Think about why for the serialize functions of PHP Objects can implement __sleep and __wakeup methods.

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not carry with it information on the type (class) of an object, it is a Javacript object literal. The only information it carries is the names and values of the properties.

If you want to encode a PHP object to a string in a way that it can be converted back to a PHP object of the correct type, you will need to [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it.

Answer (score 1):

How would PHP know where your JSON comes from or how *you* intend to use it? JSON by itself does not carry any such information, and `json_decode` does not provide any such functionality.

If you want your class instances to be serializable to JSON you will need to fill in the blanks manually, perhaps starting from something like this:

```
class Foo {
    public function toJSON() {
        return json_encode($this);
    }

    public static function fromJSON($json) {
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        $foo = new Foo;
        foreach ($obj as $prop => $value) {
            $foo->$prop = $value;
        }

        return $foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this using a factory pattern to reconstruct the object, but as I was writing it I realised it's of limited use since it would only be able to cope with the most basic structures of a single object or at best an array of objects that would need to be of the same type. Really he needs to `serialize()` - if this needs to be transmitted as JSON he could wrap the serialized strings into another structure and `json_encode()` that.

Comment: @DaveRandom: That's a prominent option but I wouldn't be so fast to eliminate pure JSON. If there's JS code that wants to consume the JSON how is it going to sort out the serialized representation?

Comment: True, I suppose one could add an additional property to the objects indicating their class, although this then breaks simple iterations over the object. It depends heavily on the application - if the JSON is a simple 1- or 2-dimensional structure containing only 1 type of object it's easy, but anything more complex than that starts to get horribly complicated very quickly. For your troubles, I think I shall bestow upon you this tasty +1 that I have lying around on my desk :-D

Comment: Thank you Jon, this is what I was searching!